# Pipeline for item not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, serialization, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I am trying to write output of a scraped xml to json. The scrape fails due to an item not being serializable.

From this question its advised that you need to build a pipeline, answer not provided out of scope for question [SO scrapy serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27391649/461887)

So referring to scrapy [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-a-json-file) 
It illustrates an example, however the docs then advise not to use this

> The purpose of JsonWriterPipeline is just to introduce how to write
>   item pipelines. If you really want to store all scraped items into a
>   JSON file you should use the Feed exports.

If I go to feed exports this is shown

> JSON
>
> FEED_FORMAT: json Exporter used: JsonItemExporter See this warning if
>   you’re using JSON with large feeds.

My issue still remains as that as i understand is for executing from command line as such.

```
scrapy runspider myxml.py -o ~/items.json -t json
```

However, this creates the error I was aiming to use a pipeline to solve.

```
TypeError: <bound method SelectorList.extract of [<Selector xpath='.//@venue' data=u'Royal Randwick'>]> is not JSON serializable
```

How do I create the json pipeline to rectify the json serialize error?

This is my code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
from scrapy.selector import XmlXPathSelector
from conv_xml.items import ConvXmlItem
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/27391649/461887
import json


class MyxmlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "myxml"

    start_urls = (
        ["file:///home/sayth/Downloads/20160123RAND0.xml"]
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        sites = sel.xpath('//meeting')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = ConvXmlItem()
            item['venue'] = site.xpath('.//@venue').extract
            item['name'] = site.xpath('.//race/@id').extract()
            item['url'] = site.xpath('.//race/@number').extract()
            item['description'] = site.xpath('.//race/@distance').extract()
            items.append(item)

        return items


        # class JsonWriterPipeline(object):
        #
        #     def __init__(self):
        #         self.file = open('items.jl', 'wb')
        #
        #     def process_item(self, item, spider):
        #         line = json.dumps(dict(item)) + "\n"
        #         self.file.write(line)
        #         return item
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
item['venue'] = site.xpath('.//@venue').extract
```

You've just forgot to call `extract`. Replace it with:

```
item['venue'] = site.xpath('.//@venue').extract()
```

Comment: lol I hate it when you go on a giant big chase down a pointless rabbit hole, thanks

Comment: I went down that same damn rabbit hole thanks - fixed my issue.